# NetBeans go to error in a class (Java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an exclamation sign in a large Java class in NetBeans. Is there a way to go to the line with an error message?

Comment: wow, try to be for a moment at our side of the network, and imagine how much information is your question bringing us.... we dont even know what the error is....

Comment: So, what exactly you don

Comment: this part is not clear:
***I have an exclamation sign in a large Java class in NetBeans. Is there a way to go to the line with an error message?***

Comment: @ΦXoce웃Пepeúpa I think he means an exclamation sign next to the class name in the project explorer, which means that the class has a compilation error.

Comment: The tab with a given class shows an exclamation sign (means an error is there). I ask if there is a hotkey that would bring mer to the first error in a class (much like Ctrl-F allows to search for text in file or "diff" arrow allows to see next diff).

Comment: Attaching an image will help

Answer (score 3):

Netbean/Eclipse will show you the compile time error with line number. Ctrl+ F can be used to find "!" sign if thats what you want!
If you use javac to compile your code you can get the line where you are having compile time error.

Comment: I am looking for a hotkey to go to the line with an error. Ctrl-F allows to search for text in a class, but doesn't allow to search fro the "error tag". Looking for a small red line is hard when there are many other lines (warnings "use lambda", "change order of operands", etc  left from previous devs).

Comment: use javac "JAVA_CLASS"  using CLI , it will be handy in this case at least

Answer (score 3):

There should be a red line in the right margin where the error is (start there if the class is large to scroll to approximately where the line is ***by clicking on the red line***). There should also be a bulb with a red exclamation sign in the left margin on the specific line. And finally the statement itself should be underlined in red.

[image]

Alternatively, if you build the project you will see compilation error(s) with links to the corresponding line(s) of code - that may not be desirable in some situations where rebuilding the whole project is expensive.